# Why BindingList<T> RemoveItem method is protected

Tags: c#, winforms, bindinglist

Tell me please, why BindingList RemoveItem method is protected? What is the purpose of it? I know I can just inherit from it but the question is why one have made this protected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is protected because `BindingList<T>` is based on [`Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397), and `RemoveItem` is intended for implementations of `Collection<T>` to provide the proper, collection-specific implementation.

To use this directly, you can use the public [RemoveAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132414.aspx) method.  This calls `RemoveItem` internally, but is the public-facing API for removing an item by index.

Comment: It works. Thank you :) I missed this because thought that as it is Collection member it will not raise ListChanged event.